# O que posso usar pra substituir o input hidden no ASP NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou com uma missão dificil que é passar um sistema de webforms para MVC, o sistema com webforms possui muitos input hiddens que guardam informações básicas como hash da sessão e código do usuário, mas como eu, na minha humilde opinião, acho meio inseguro e até trabalhoso usar input hiddens em MVC, eu posso usar outra coisa no lugar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Sinceramente eu não entendi a parte insegurança, trabalhoso que difere isso do WebForms para MVC. Trivialmente falando não tem como evitar tal duvida, você por acaso poderia então colocar porque você acha inseguro e trabalhoso, com um exemplo???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o objeto [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) para armazenar as informações do usuário.

O objeto Session permite que o desenvolvedor obtenha os dados, previamente persistidos na sessão, por tempo determinado na Session (default 20 minutos). Mas, utilize este recurso com moderação, armazenando somente os dados necessário de seu usuário, uma vez que os dados da session são armazenados por padrão em memória, muitos dados podem desencadear problemas de escalabilidade.

```
//Variáveis do usuário
string firstName = "Jeff";
string lastName = "Smith";
string city = "Seattle";

//Salvando informações na sessão.
Session["FirstName"] = firstName;
Session["LastName"] = lastName;
Session["City"] = city;

//Lendo variáveis da sessão.
firstName = (string)(Session["FirstName"]);
lastName = (string)(Session["LastName"]);
city = (string)(Session["City"]);
```

**Exemplo:**

```
public class MeuController
{
    //Trabalhando com a session em uma propriedade do controller
    public static Pessoa dadosPessoa
    {
        get
        {
             if(Http.Context.Current.Session["pessoaX"] == null)
             {
                 Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
                 //Cria uma variável na session chamada pessoaX contendo um objeto p
                 Http.Context.Current.Session["pessoaX"] = p;
                 return p;    
             }
             else
             {
                 return (Pessoa)Http.Context.Current.Session["pessoaX"];
             }
         }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         //Recuperando dados previamente persistidos na sessão
         var pessoa = (Pessoa)(Session["pessoaX"]);

         var lista = obterDadosRepositorio(pessoa);
         return View("Index", lista)    
    }

} 

//Acessando dados na view com Razor
@{ var sessionVar = Session["pessoaX"]; }

ou 

<%= this.Session["pessoaX"] %>
```

Quando um usuário logar na sua aplicação, você poderia preencher e adicionar um objeto com os dados desse usuário na session e recuperar quando desejado.

Comment: Farei assim ! Obrigado!

Comment: É bom lembrar que, apesar de correta, esta abordagem já é ultrapassada e o uso de `Sessions` desta forma deve ser desencorajado, em prol de classes como `Request` e `User`.

Comment: ViewBag, ViewData são mais indicados.

Answer (score 3):

Não há qualquer motivo para sentir essa falta de segurança. Só deve ser exposto na *View* dados que possam ser manipulados por ela.

No caso do WebForms, o que ocorre é que essas informações são escritas na *View* por uma limitação do Framework, e não porque necessariamente o Framework é mais seguro. Por exemplo, no MVC não é preciso utilizar Hash de sessão porque todas as informações que você precisa podem ser acessadas através de classes mais alto nível como `Request` e classes que implementam `IPrincipal`. Essas últimas guardam as informações do usuário e podem ser extendidas.

Em todo caso, havendo dúvidas neste processo de conversão, você pode fazer perguntas em específico sobre alguma etapa que você estiver tendo dificuldade. A comunidade daqui apresentará respostas para que você resolva seu problema da melhor maneira possível.